# Format Date from string in one format back to string then parse string to date

Tags: java, date

Im trying to grab a string(date) parse with ("MM/dd/yyyy") then format date from the string with
("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy") then parse that string again creating date with format ("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy"). So I can compare two dates with format ("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy")

Not getting any parsing errors but Im trying to use this to compare two dates. Running into issue with not being able to create list because my compare isnt working. Need a little help with this type of conversion

```
                  private Date getDateNDaysAgo(int numDays) {
                  log.debug("getDateNDaysAgo 1 " + numDays);
                  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                  Date returnDate = null;
                  cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -(numDays));
                  returnDate = cal.getTime();
                  log.debug("getDateNDaysAgo 2" + returnDate);
                  return (returnDate);
                  }                 

              String EffectiveHireString = null;
              String EffectiveHireDate = null;
              
              
              Date returnEffectiveHireDate = null;
              Date thresholdDate = null;
              Date newEffectiveHireDate=null;
              boolean isAccountCreatedOver25Days = false; 

              link = (Link)itrLinkResults.next();

              // only pull active accounts
              if(!link.isDisabled()) {
              if(link.getAttribute("lastLogon") != null){
              log.debug("QueryParameter: lastLogon (1): not null");
              lastLogon = link.getAttribute("lastLogon");
              }

              if(link.getAttribute("EffectiveHireDate") != null){
              log.debug("QueryParameter: EffectiveHireDate (1): not null");
              acuEffectiveHireDate  = link.getAttribute("EffectiveHireDate");

              if(Util.isNotNullOrEmpty(EffectiveHireDate)) {

              DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy"); 
              SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
              SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy");
              try {
                  
                newEffectiveHireDate = sdf.parse(EffectiveHireDate);
                EffectiveHireString = df.format(newEffectiveHireDate);
                returnEffectiveHireDate = formatter.parse(EffectiveHireString);
                
                thresholdDate = getDateNDaysAgo(25);
                log.debug("thresholdDate" + thresholdDate);

               if(returnEffectiveHireDate.compareTo(thresholdDate) &lt; 0){
              log.debug("returnEffectiveHireDate 2" + returnEffectiveHireDate);
              isAccountCreatedOver25Days = true;** 
              }
              }
                  catch (ParseException e) {
                  log.error("Error attempting to parse EffectiveHireDate Date");
                  }
                  }
                  }
```

Comment: *but Im trying to use this to compare two dates.*  It would be helpful if you would explain the criteria for comparison.  Also, you say compare dates but your format contains time elements.

Comment: Your question is convoluted and confusing. Rewrite for clarity. Tips: (a) Never use `Date`/`Calendar`/`DateFormat`. They were supplanted years ago by *java.time* classes. (b) Do not generate localized strings for parsing. Use only standard ISO 8601 formats for data exchange. The *java.time* classes use the standard formats by default for generating/parsing strings. (c) When posting code here, strip it down to the bare minimum needed to show your issue.

Comment: Im comparing date/times to see if users have logged into a system within 25 days. These are the classes I have to work with.

Comment: Im having issue with the string to date parse - format to string then parse back to date.

Comment: You say "These are the classes I have to work with." Why? Are you on a very old version of Java? Are you on Android? (There are versions of the java.time API for Android.)

Comment: This is beanshell and the classes the application supports.

Answer (score 1):

There is a conceptual problem with what you are trying to do. You are taking a date in the format MM/dd/yyyy and converting it to a string representation that has date, time, and time zone, but your initial data contains only date, not time or time zone. Of course, you can set the time to 00:00:00 and the time zone to your system default, but these are assumptions that may be incorrect.

In any case, here is how you could do it using the java.time API:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;

// . . .

    DateTimeFormatter mdy = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy");
    String date = "01/28/2022";
    
    // the follow steps could be combined, but they are separated for clarity
    LocalDate localDate = mdy.parse(date, LocalDate::from);
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(localDate, LocalTime.of(0, 0));
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(ldt, ZoneId.systemDefault);
    
    // formatted as "Fri Jan 28 24:00:00 EST 2022"
    String formatted = formatter.format(zdt);
    ZonedDateTime parsed = formatter.parse(formatted, ZonedDateTime::from);
    // parsed.equals(zdt) == true
    // parsed.compareTo(zdt) == 0
```

If you really just want to compare dates, I would strongly suggest using only the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class and leaving time and time zone out of it entirely.

Here is an example using only Date, Calendar, and (Simple)DateFormat:

```
boolean checkEffectiveHireDate(String hireDateMMddyyyy) throws ParseException {
    DateFormat mmddyyyy = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    DateFormat fullFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy");
    Date hireDate = mmddyyyy.parse(hireDateMMddyyyy);
    String effectiveHire = fullFormat.format(hireDate);
    System.out.println(effectiveHire);
    Date effectiveHireDate = fullFormat.parse(effectiveHire);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -25);
    Date thresholdDate = cal.getTime();
    return effectiveHireDate.compareTo(thresholdDate) < 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the leg up. The time zone if requirement. I I will test output

Comment: Im still getting parse errors when trying to use same date formats

Comment: @nmeagher I just tried it with Calendar, Date, and SimpleDateFormat, and I didn't get any errors. What is the error you are getting? What is the string that it is not able to parse? What version of Java are you using?

Comment: @nmeagher The `checkEffectiveHireDate` I just added returns `false` for `"01/20/2022"` and `true` for `"01/02/2022"` and does not throw a `ParseException` in either case. I am using an early access build of JDK 18, but I also tried it with JDK 11.0.9 and JDK 1.8.0_311.

Comment: I fat fingered a missing closing bracket. Using Date, Calendar, and (Simple)DateFormat worked. Thanks for your help